# Excel: Sort column to match values of another column

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I've got a problem with an excel sheet with 4 columns where two columns rely on each other because Column A is the name and column B is the quantity, the same thing with columns C and D.

```
Table
==========================================
A            B             C             D
Apple        54            Banana        12
Peanut        6            Pineapple      4
Cranberry   112            Cherry        40
Cookie        3            Peanut         4
Banana        2            Cranberry      5
Peach         3            Almond        10
Cherry        5               
Cheese       10
```

What I want to get is that each content of column C with the quantity in column D will be placed in the same row as their matching part in column A so I can compare the quantities between B and D. All the values with no matching partner should be placed at the bottom or just with an empty table, so I know there is no match.

Example how it should look like:

```
Table
==========================================
A            B             C             D
Apple        54            
Peanut        6            Peanut         4
Cranberry   112            Cranberry      5
Cookie        3            
Banana        2            Banana        12
Peach         3            
Cherry        5            Cherry        40 
Cheese       10            
                           Almond        10
                           Pineapple      4
```

Comment: Move your second data set over a few columns then use VLOOKUP to reference that  data, bringing it back in order and in place.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem: `=VLOOKUP(C2;$A$2:$B$9;2;TRUE)`
You simply add this as a column "E" in your spreadsheet and drag it down then you can compare the values.

Answer (score 0):

Col A remains as it is.
Col B remains as it is.
Col C moves to Col E.
Col D moves to Col F.

New Col C, Cell C1 = `=IFS(AND(A1<>"",(COUNTIF($E$1:E, A1)=1)=TRUE),A1,AND(A1<>"",(COUNTIF($E$1:E, A1)=1)=FALSE),"",A1="",ArrayFormula(INDEX($E$1:E,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($E$1:E,$A$1:A,0)),(ROW($E$1:E)-MIN(ROW($A$1:A))+1),""),SUM(ROW(1:1)-COUNTA($A$1:A1))))))`

Copy this down from C1

New Col D, Cell D1 = `=IF(C1="","",VLOOKUP(C1,$E$1:F,2,FALSE))`

Note: I wrote this in Google sheets, So when I type `ctrl + shift + enter` it coverts it into `ArrayFormula()`. You will need to do an array formula the excel way - `ctrl + shift + enter` and remove the `ArrayFormula()`.

Feel free to view this in a sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10hygbPyzj7L1u77izejoeGriaquoZ_omp49pCJ2U7uE/edit?usp=sharing

If you want to export the sheet. Right click the "sheet 1" tab, go to "copy to" and "new spreadsheet"

Any questions, let me know :)

Comment: @Ves Was this solution viable?

Comment: Hi, I am using Excel 2010 and it might be the reason why some parts of your code don't work for me. My Excel version doesn't allow commas but semicolons. The entire part of the ```ArrayFormula``` with ``` ctrl + shift +enter``` appears not to work for me.

The link to your sheet doesn't work for me. Can you provide another link so I can take a look and maybe get an idea of how it works?

Comment: The Function IFS doesn't exist in Excel 2010. I'm not sure why, but I had to re-approve the link-sharing. Please try again, it should be working.

Comment: At home, I only have google sheets, I will look to see if I can amend the formula in excel on monday morning (UK time) for you. So it works in your version. In the mean time, please re-check the link to see if you are happy with the likely end result :)